# Datatables Dom Positioning Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to use custom DOM positioning with Bootstrap rows and columns.

```html
<!-- I want it like below -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 buton">
    {Buttons}
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 veriler">
    {PageLength}
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "searching": false,
    "dom": '<"buton"B><"veriler"l><"top"Cr>t<"bottom"ip><"clear">',
    buttons: ['copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print', 'colvis']
  });
});
```

Comment: And the issue you're having is?

Answer (score 0):

i solved problem. solution is below.

```
"dom":'<"row"<"col-sm-6"B><"col-sm-3"><"col-sm-3"l>>tr<"bottom"<"row"<"col-sm-6"i><"col-sm-6"p>>><"clear">'
```